# Automatically creating subplots in plotly (e.g. Facetting in R)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, flexdashboard, ggplotly

I'm quite comfortable using the tidyverse and ggplot. I'm trying to produce an interactive graph to deploy with flexdashboard. I'm therefore trying to generate my usual ggplots in plotly.

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
data.frame(id = c(1:5),
           product = c("product1","product2","product1","product3","product2"),
           variable = c("var1","var1","var3","var2","var1"),
           price = c(100,120,140,90,80))
```

With output:

```
  id  product variable price
1  1 product1     var1   100
2  2 product2     var1   120
3  3 product1     var3   140
4  4 product3     var2    90
5  5 product2     var1    80
```

If I want to display all of this on a plot, I would do the following in ggplot:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(hrbrthemes)

data.frame(id = c(1:5),
           product = c("product1","product2","product1","product3","product2"),
           variable = c("var1","var1","var3","var2","var1"),
           price = c(100,120,140,90,80)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = id, y = price, color = variable)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~product) +
  theme_ft_rc()
```

Which woud yield:

[image: Sample Plot]

I understand I can achieve something similar in plotly by using the `subplot()`
function. The issues is that I have somewhere between 14-28 categories to plot as facets. Which as far as I understand, would mean that I would have to produce 14-28 plots and then arrange them in a grid. It seems a bit tedious and I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to achieve that, such as the facet option in ggplot. I also got a snippet of code on another post:

```
library(plotly)

dataframe <- data.frame(id = c(1:5),
           product = c("product1","product2","product1","product3","product2"),
           variable = c("var1","var1","var3","var2","var1"),
           price = c(100,120,140,90,80)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "product", values_from = "price")

vars <- setdiff(names(dataframe),"id")

plots <- lapply(vars, function(var){
   plot_ly(dataframe, x = ~id, color =~variable, y = as.formula(paste0("~",var))) %>%
  add_bars(name = var)
 })
 subplot(plots, nrows = length(plots), shareX = TRUE, titleX = FALSE)
```

Which yields:

[image]

and requires to use tidyr's `pivot_wider()` function with the `product` column in the sample frame. However, my real columns contain numbers and characters, which yields an error when using the above sample code. The variable column is also displayed in an odder manner. Is there are workaround to this issue, or is the best way truly to manually write the code for every single plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your first example (I just removed your theme styling) it works like this.

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1:5),
  product = c("product1","product2","product1","product3","product2"),
  variable = c("var1","var1","var3","var2","var1"),
  price = c(100,120,140,90,80)
)

plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = id, y = price, color = variable)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~product)

ggplotly(plot)
```

[image]

The only difference is that I did not chain with %>% as it seems that plotly throws an error when I try this below:

```
data.frame(
  id = c(1:5),
  product = c("product1","product2","product1","product3","product2"),
  variable = c("var1","var1","var3","var2","var1"),
  price = c(100,120,140,90,80)
) %>% ggplot(aes(x = id, y = price, color = variable)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~product) %>% ggplotly()

# Error in UseMethod("ggplotly", p) : 
#   no applicable method for 'ggplotly' applied to an object of class "c('FacetWrap', 'Facet', 'ggproto', 'gg')"
```

**Extended example with custom tooltip**

You can make it as fancy as you like, I added price formatting and for the fun of it combined product and variable as one line in the tooltip.

```
custom_tooltip <- paste0("ID: ", df$id, "\n", "Product: ", df$product, " (", df$variable, ")\n", "Sold for: £ ", df$price)

plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = id, y = price, color = variable)) +
  geom_point(aes(text = custom_tooltip)) +
  facet_wrap(~product)

ggplotly(plot, tooltip = c("text"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I guess I can try that way. My issue with ggplotly is that it sometimes formats the plot in a weird way. And mostly that I cannot seem to find how to properly format the hover text such that it would display something like ```paste("£", price)```

Comment: you can rewrite the text for the tooltip, give me a second to add it to my answer.

Comment: Oh thanks, that's actually amazing, I've been struggling with this tooltip issue all week. I didn't know you had to pass it into the plot type ```aes()```. Thank you so much for that solution, I'll try and edit my question a bit so that it reflects your answer.
The only issue is that my facet plot is formatted in a weird way. I have 22 subplots in the facet. The first row appears normally, so does the last. But the middle three rows are compressed flat and illegible as a result. Do you happen to know why?

Comment: Is that using the ggplot code and then make it a ggplotly or do you get that facetting issue using subplots?

Comment: No, I'm creating the same facet plot as above using ggplot2, and then passing it to plotly through ggplotly. It works fine if I do  a single dotplot for one product, but when I facet all of them the formatting is random. I'll try to make reproduce my issue as an example.

Comment: Yes try to share a dput of some data that reproduces that scenario. I never have encountered such an issue. But sure I can give it a try if I can reproduce your scenario.

Comment: Hey, I tried to make a reproduceable example, but I haven't managed so far. I'll toss one in if I manage. But in any case, thank you very much for all the assistance!